# Ignoring diectories when using Spring Roo

Tags: spring, spring-roo, roo

Do you know if there's a way to ignore directories when using Spring Roo? We are currently developing a project with roo, and we would like roo to ignore the CVS folders...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Roo only scans that files that it knows and it can manage. That is, those that have been annotated with its annotations or those that it considers that is necessary to apply some changes.

So, why do you want to exclude a folder that doesn't contain files managed by Spring Roo? Which kind of error are you getting?

Regards,

Comment: I'm actually getting the following error when the Roo console loades: NullPointerException at com.github.antlrjavaparser.adapter.StatementContextAdapter.adapt <StatemenetContextAdapter.70> I thought that it could have something to do with CVS files, this error appeared when we changed from GIT to CVS...

Comment: Which version of Spring Roo are you using? Could you provide more info? sample project?

Comment: We've used versión 1.2.5 and we are currently using versión 1.3.2.
It's an enterprise app, so i can't provide the code.
We hace o ver 2000 classes, so it's difficult to review them all

Comment: Is a little bit difficult to provide a valid solution without some sample code or some proof of concept that shows that issue... maybe creating some `clinic.roo` applicaton and including CVS files are you able to reproduce it?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the error as you said but I'm not able to do it :( I think there has to be something that Roo doesn't like in an specific class...